# Read an XML file with Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, xml, xmlhttprequest

I'm using Javascript to read an XML file. First, what i'm doing is to save the file and then try to read it. The problem is that i receive an undefined or an "HTMLCollection" response on the console.

Here my code so far after to save the doc:

```
    var Connect = new XMLHttpRequest();

      Connect.open("GET", '//'+ $scope.UrlCardFileOne, true);

      Connect.send();

      var theDocument = Connect.responseXML;

      var parser = new DOMParser();
      var doc = parser.parseFromString(Connect, 'application/xml');


      var test = doc.getElementsByTagName('cfdi:Comprobante');
      console.log(test);

      /*for(var i = 0; i< test.length; i++){
        var secondTest = test[i];
        console.log(secondTest);
      }*/
      });
```

The `cfdi:Comprobante` is the very first of the tags. If I use the code like this the response is "HTMLCollection". If i try with:

```
var test = doc.getElementsByTagName('cfdi:Comprobante')[0];
```

The response is `undefined`. And if i try with:

```
var test = doc.getElementsByTagName('cfdi:Comprobante')[0].childNodes[0];
```

I get an error because there's no childNodes of undefined. Someone can help me please?

Is the first time i'm working with XML, so if something is missing or there's something wrong, hope you can guide me.

I'm working with javascript and AngularJs.

Thanx in advance.

Comment: With AngularJS, use the [`$http` Service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http). It wraps the `xmlhttprequest` in a service that returns an AngularJS promise that is integrated with the AngularJS execution context. Only operations which are applied in the AngularJS execution context will benefit from AngularJS data-binding, exception handling, property watching, etc.

Comment: `XMLHttpRequest.responseXML` returns a DOM Document object, not a string ...